# Comparison Between Average Kernel (Box Kernel) and Gaussian Kernel

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, gaussian

In image processing, we have two kinds of major kernels that are average kernel and Gaussian kernel. For image segmentation, which is difference between average kernel and Gaussian kernel? I found some paper said that they are similar, and average kernel implement faster than Gaussian kernel, right?When we use average kernel

Comment: Could you please review my answer?

Comment: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22/

Answer (score 0):

If you pre calculate the filter coefficients the complexity of the convolution is set by its radius only.

Yet, if all coefficients are the same, it could be reduced into summation and one normalization multiplication.

Yet, I don't think it will have major effect on modern CPU's.
Certainly not on those who supports fused multiply and addition.

Comment: Except that for an average filter the coefficient for each input point is 1, so you only have one multiplication.

Comment: You're right. I will mention this.

Comment: I read that average kernel similar gaussian kernel but it take larger error than gaussian kernel. So, when we use average kernel?

Comment: What can be done is to approximate the Gaussian Blur by "Box Blur" (Average Blur). See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489902/approximating-gaussian-blur-using-extended-box-blur

Comment: Another optimisation with the average filter is that you can maintain column sums as you iterate, so for each new point you just calculate one new column sum. This means that an NxN average filter can be implemented with just 2N-2 adds rather than N^2-1 adds.

Comment: Why would you need 2N-2 adds? Calculating a running sum for each row takes one add per pixel, calculating a box filter from that takes another subtraction. Then repeat that for each column. That makes 4 additions and one multiplication per pixel, no matter what N is.

Comment: @nikie: yes, you can make it more efficient computationally if you treat it as a separable filter, but this generally requires two passes through the data. For a single pass you can use the column sum optimisation I mentioned above - although it's not as optimal it lends itself well to SIMD/GPGPU optimisation and is also more cache-friendly.

Comment: @Drazick: thanks - I don't really have time right now, but I may get to it later...

Comment: For a large images on modern processors, cache locality and memory latency may affect performance far more than the number of MACs or adds in each kernel.  For GPGPUs, the time to load/unload texture/local memory.  For smaller kernels, the arithmetic might be essentially free in terms of performance, depending on how you tile your filter operation compared to the image data layout.

Answer (score -1):

Average Filter (Box Blur) can be approximated using [Integral Images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table) / [Running Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).
In those efficient methods their complexity depends on the size of the image only and not the radius of the filter.

Gaussian Blur is often approximated by repetitive Box Blur (Hence, in this method, is slower) hence also has ability to be approximated by operation with complexity of the size of the image only.